# A child container failed during start - Problem whith Tomcat 9 and Netbeans

Tags: tomcat9

I need your help whith this problem in Netbeans and Tomcat 9 when I need started the Tomcat, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@161b062a]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source):

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@161b062a]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@161b062a]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4758)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4893)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Users\UT\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\webapps\vortal] is not valid
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 30 more

sep 06, 2019 4:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
... 13 more

sep 06, 2019 4:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)

sep 06, 2019 4:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sep 06, 2019 4:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sep 06, 2019 4:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Parando servicio [Catalina]
sep 06, 2019 4:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sep 06, 2019 4:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main exception seems to be this line:

```
The main resource set specified [C:\Users\UT\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\webapps\vortal] is not valid
```

Try to clear Tomcat working directory.

Comment: I already  cleared Tomcat working directory, but the problem continue.